# Please help with Bitcoin Core. Password

Tags: wallet

All kind time of day. From the Internet I learned about Bitcoin. Decided to support this movement. Downloaded Bitcoin Core put 0.5 BTC to buy two S9. At the beginning of the habit to put password and when the time came to transfer the BTC realised that a password is forgotten. Attempts to recall were not successful. Waiting for the wise advice how to be and what to do to restore the wallet. Thanks in advance if you have understanding and support.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid, you can not recover your wallet without the password. That is the idea of the password: if someone steals your wallet, she can do nothing without the password.

So, try hard and do recall the password.

Answer (score 0):

if you remember at least some characters of your password you could brute-force it.

watch this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uV2AYO8JQSA).

Comment: Спасибо за внимание к проблеме. Боюсь сам не осилю но пробовать буду. Мне интересно почему я со своего IP не могу зайти в настройки кошелька зайти за изменением пароля. Ведь он загружен на мой IP и изменять на нём тоже должно быть, иначе логика где? это же МОЙ кошелёк.

Comment: Sorry, i can't speak Russian and I'm afraid of google translation.

Comment: He afraid the Google translator so translate on Yandex, but he is naughty. And yet your opinion is important to me.

Comment: I myself am afraid of the Google translator so I translate it on Yandex, but he's naughty. And yet your opinion is important to me. Here is an experiment. google is better.